# Cant call function due to arguments

Tags: python

Basically I'm making a Caesar cipher but when I added functions and included arguments the while loop at the bottom can't call the function. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Sorry if the format of the code looks kinda odd but I only need to fix the functions and arguments

Thanks in advance.

```
flag = 0

small_chars = [chr(item) for item in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]
upper_chars = [item.upper() for item in small_chars]

def encryptionfunction(chr_item, is_upper_case):
    '''
    Cipher each chr_item.
    '''
    # setting orig and end order.
    if is_upper_case:
        orig_ord = ord('A')
        end_ord  = ord('Z')
    else:
        orig_ord = ord('a')
        end_ord  = ord('z')

    # calculating shift    
    temp_ord = ord(chr_item)+shift
    # calculating offset order with modulo.
    # char is after end_ord, calculating offset
    num_of_chars = 26
    offset_ord = (temp_ord - end_ord - 1)%num_of_chars
    return chr(orig_ord + offset_ord)

# enable while loop to repeat until status not 'y'
    status = 'y'
    while status == 'y':
    # enter word to cipher.
        word = input("Word: ")
    # enter char shift
    shift = 5
    print

    # create cipher list variable
    cipher = list()
    # loop trough each char in word
    for chr_item in word:
        # encode just letters.
        # replace non-alfa with underscore: "_"
        if chr_item in upper_chars or chr_item in small_chars:
            # set is_uppser_case to True for upper case chars.
            is_upper_case = (chr_item in upper_chars) and True
            # cipher char.
            temp_chr = encryptionfunction(chr_item, is_upper_case)
            # append ciphered char to list
            cipher.append(temp_chr)
        elif chr_item is ' ':
            cipher.append(chr_item)
        else:
            cipher.append('_')

    # print ciphered word
    print (''.join(cipher))

def decryptionfunction(chr_item, is_upper_case):
    '''
    Cipher each chr_item.
    '''
    # setting orig and end order.
    if is_upper_case:
        orig_ord = ord('A')
        end_ord  = ord('Z')
    else:
        orig_ord = ord('a')
        end_ord  = ord('z')

    # calculating shift    
    temp_ord = ord(chr_item)+shift
    # calculating offset order with modulo.
    # char is after end_ord, calculating offset
    num_of_chars = 26
    offset_ord = (temp_ord - end_ord - 1)%num_of_chars
    return chr(orig_ord - offset_ord)

# enable while loop to repeat until status not 'y'
    status = 'y'
    while status == 'y':
    # enter word to cipher.
        word = input("Word: ")
    # enter char shift
    shift = 5
    print

    # create cipher list variable
    cipher = list()
    # loop trough each char in word
    for chr_item in word:
        # encode just letters.
        # replace non-alfa with underscore: "_"
        if chr_item in upper_chars or chr_item in small_chars:
            # set is_uppser_case to True for upper case chars.
            is_upper_case = (chr_item in upper_chars) and True
            # cipher char.
            temp_chr = encryptionfunction(chr_item, is_upper_case)
            # append ciphered char to list
            cipher.append(temp_chr)
        elif chr_item is ' ':
            cipher.append(chr_item)
        else:
            cipher.append('_')

    # print ciphered word
    print (''.join(cipher))


while flag == 0:
    answer=input("Would you like to encrypt(1) or decrypt(2)?: ")

    if answer == "encrypt":
        flag = 1
        encryptionfunction(chr_item, is_upper_case)

    elif answer == "1":
        flag = 1
        encryptionfunction(chr_item, is_upper_case)

    elif answer == "decrypt":
        flag = 2
        decryptionfunction(chr_item, is_upper_case)

    elif answer == "2":
        flag = 2
        decryptionfunction(chr_item, is_upper_case)

    else:
        print("Please enter a vaild answer. ")
```

Comment: what is `chr_item`, `is_upper_case` here you are passing as argument inside while loop ?

Comment: When I enter 1 to encrypt it gave me an error: TypeError: encryptionfunction() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'chr_item' and 'is_upper_case'

Comment: Where is your `encode_chr` function ?

Comment: opps thats is supposed to be encryptionfunction

Comment: Your cypher function looks much more complicated than it should ! (normally I guess this can be done in 5 lines or so)

Comment: I have tried many different methods but none have seemed to work. It usually comes down to only alphabet validation and being able to have a space in between in the output. I have had the most success with this method so far